# Inno Setup: How to get return values from custom wizard pages?

Tags: inno-setup, wizard

I have to build an install routine for a database. So far, it has been pretty easy to create this bunch of code (thanks to Inno Script Studio).

Now I have to ask the user who's installing our software, which `authentication` mode he wants to use (**Windows NT/SQL Server Authentification**). After that (**IF SQL Server Authentication was chosen**) there should appear another custom wizard page, which asks the user for the odbc name, server name, user and password (to create the `.ini` file).

I managed to get the custom wizard pages to work with the following code:

```
[Code]
var
  LightMsgPage: TOutputMsgWizardPage;
  AskAuthPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;
  ServerDataPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { Create the pages }
  LightMsgPage:= CreateOutputMsgPage(wpWelcome,
    'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX',
    'XXXXXXX ' +
    'XXXXXXX.');

  AskAuthPage := CreateInputOptionPage(LightMsgPage.ID,
    'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX',
    'XXXXXXX',
    True, False);
  AskAuthPage.Add('XXXXXXX');
  AskAuthPage.Add('XXXXXXX');

  ServerDataPage := CreateInputQueryPage(AskAuthPage.ID,
    'XXXXXXX', '',
    'XXXXXXX');
  ServerDataPage.Add('ODBC Name:', False);
  ServerDataPage.Add('Server Name:', False);
  ServerDataPage.Add('User:', False);
  ServerDataPage.Add('Password:', False);
end;
```

At first, when I start the routine I get a "Welcome Message" (LightMsgPage). If I click Next, I get to the Page with two Option Buttons (AskAuthPage).

Here starts the problem:
If I choose Option 1, it should skip the **ServerDataPage** and went straight to the page where you can set your installation path on `hdd`.
If I choose Option 2, the **ServerDataPage** with its input fields should appear.

I know from the example from `Inno` Setup that there's a way to skip pages:

```
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  { Skip pages that shouldn't be shown }
  if (PageID = LightMsgPage.ID) and (UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex <> 0) then
    Result := True
  else if (PageID = KeyPage.ID) and (UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex <> 2) then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

I'm absolutely clear about how this function works. But how do I access the values from the previous pages? Can I store them in a variable or something? I can't find something, maybe I'm just blind or an idiot.

If someone can help me I would be very thankful.

Greetings

Comment: You can set Global Variables instead of Local Variables per `Function` /  `Procedure`. You can also copy value of Local Variable to Global Variable if needed. In your example the `LightMsgPage` is Global Variable for whole `[Code]` section.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. It seems that you have everything in place. Except that your page name is `AskAuthPage`, not `UsagePage`.

Comment: That means how the user decides (Option 1 or 2) is stored in "AskAuthPage" ?

Comment: Yes, `AskAuthPage.SelectedValueIndex`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I just dont know where Inno Setup stores the value how the user has decided. Thats my only problem :D

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks, I will test this. :)